# Use awk to fix CSV file with commas in unenclosed fields

Tags: macos, csv, awk

I have a CSV file which looks like:

```
  height,  comment, name
  152,  he was late, for example, on Tuesday, Fred
  162, , Sam
```

I cannot parse this file because it includes a variable number of unenclosed commas in the comment field (but no other fields). I would like to fix the file using `awk` (which is very new to me) so that the commas in the second field become semi-colons:

```
  height,  comment, name
  152,  he was late; for example; on Tuesday, Fred
  162, , Sam
```

(Enclosing the entire field in quotes will not solve my problem because my CSV parser does not understand quotes.)

So far I am looking at using NF to work out the number of unenclosed commas and then replacing them using gsub with an unpleasant regex, but I feel I should be able to leverage awk  to write a more readable program and I am not sure NF behaves this way.

Comment: Is there really a comma after **Fred**? That's ugly, how many fields are there, really?  If the file has random commas *other* than just the embedded ones, then I think that problem will need to be fixed first.

Comment: if you can be sure that the extra commas are in field 2 each time, the if NF==6, then you have 3 extra commas, you can change the first and last to something else temporarily, and then change the remaining commas to semicolons (one line at a time, of course). But of course, this really isn't a flexible long-term solution. Why not just export your data with a FS value that will never be in your data? Good luck.

Comment: @DigitalRoss There is no comma after Fred; that was a typo. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @shellter Unfortunately I don't have access to the original database so choosing a different FS is not an option. I am not too worried about it not being a flexible solution as the data are fixed and will not change. I will try and add a potential solution to the question.

Comment: Is the first field always a single number, and the last field always a single word?

Comment: @Catcall I would be happy to accept a solution which works for that case. In my real world problem the first field is always a number and there are four trailing fields two of which are dates (like 2013-01-01); the third is always a word and the final field is always a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially just a brute-force solution, but fairly easy to understand. Invoke with

```
$ awk -F "," -f test.awk test.dat
```

The awk file.

```
$ cat test.awk
{
    printf "%s, ", $1

    if (NF > 3) {
        for (i = 2; i < NF; i++) {
            printf "%s;", $i
        }
        printf ", "
    }
    else {
        printf "%s, ", $2
    }

    printf "%s\n", $NF
}
```

Comment: The main problem with this solution is it relies on there being one and only one blank char after every comma which of course there may not be any or there could be many and there could be tabs...

Comment: Thank you. I selected your answer because I found it easier to modify for more than three columns. I know this is not an especially good basis for distinguishing answers but I could not separate them for any good reason. I tested it for the problem @Ed describes, for example with input ```152,he was late,for example,on Tuesday,Fred``` and it worked for me, but perhaps I misunderstood. In any case my file has spaces after each comma.

Comment: @EdMorton: No, this solution doesn't rely on blanks at all. It's not affected by tabs, leading whitespace, or trailing whitespace.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice you were instructing the user to use -F, outside of your script. Why not just put BEGIN{FS=","} inside it so the user doesn't need to remember to add that argument? The script will add spaces to the original data of course.

Comment: @Catcall you mention you want to modify the script for more than 3 columns. If you have more than 3 columns then neither of the solutions posted is a good answer as they both assume all of the commas between the first and last comma need to be converted to semi-colons. You should have posted a more representative input set to get thr right solution for your real data.

Comment: I didn't want to modify it; the OP did. The OP said he found it easy to modify, which was what I expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
  height,  comment, name
  152,  he was late, for example, on Tuesday, Fred
  162, , Sam

$ awk -v OFS=, '{
   height = comment = name = $0
   sub(/,.*$/,"",height)
   sub(/^.*,/,"",name)
   gsub(/^[^,]+,|,[^,]+$/,"",comment)
   gsub(/,/,";",comment)

   print height, comment, name
}' file
  height,  comment, name
  152,  he was late; for example; on Tuesday, Fred
  162, , Sam
```